# Local storage Javascript and JSONArray

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I'm trying to storage data locally with JSONArrays and Objects. What the program does is get the value of several sliders i have inserted dynamically (sometimes 1, sometimes 2 sliders and sometimes 3 or 4...). So I get the values and the id of the product to store locally with arrays. **But there's a problem It only saves the first array, the push method doesn't work.**

Here's the code:

```
function afegir_i_editar_llistacompra(){
    //Obtenim els valors dels sliders i els guardem a localhost 
    var id_product = $('body').data('product');
    var array_of_bought_colors_new = new Array({'id': id_product});
    var array_of_bought_colors_existing = get_product_info(id_product, 'cesta_list'); 

    for (var i = 0; $('#slider-'+i).val() != null ; i++) {
        array_of_bought_colors_new.push({'color':$('#slider-'+i).attr('name'),'value': $('#slider-'+i).val()});
    };

    if(array_of_bought_colors_existing != null){
        for (var i = array_of_bought_colors_existing.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            if(array_of_bought_colors_existing[i].value != array_of_bought_colors_new[i].value)
                array_of_bought_colors_existing[i].value = array_of_bought_colors_new[i].value;
        };
    }else if( array_of_bought_colors_new.length > 1 && $('body').data('cesta_list') != null) {      
        $('body').data('cesta_list', $('body').data('cesta_list').push(array_of_bought_colors_new));
    }else{
        $('body').data('cesta_list', array_of_bought_colors_new);
    }
}
```

What I'm saving:

```
[{id:1},/*First slider -->*/{'color':'blue','value':2},/*Second slider -->*/{'color':'blue','value':32}]
```

Hope you understand!

Comment: The `.push` method works, you're probably just not calling it as often as you think. Figure out where your code goes wrong.

Comment: NITPICK: Doing `$('#slider-'+i)` over and over again is bad practice and makes you code so much slower. Store it in a variable and reuse it!

Comment: The array gets serialized when "saving"  it in localStorage

Comment: @epascarello more nitpicking: if you're dynamically generating elements you shouldn't be Sizzling them anyway, you should _know_ which elements exist.